# H.R. gossiping confidential information + using political back channels

Tags: human-resources, politics

After years without issues, our HR department has started delivering secret messages about office politics through back channels and is distributing personal and confidential information at will for political purposes. The head (director) of HR is the primary person doing this.

Short of suing the company, is there any other kind of recourse that a person could safely pursue?

*Goal:*

To stop the behavior without anything bad happening to me or spending any money.

*To clarify:*

How I know is that it's explicit. Person A and Person B came to me privately and said "the HR director told us this and that about you", etc. (*Note: They are both higher than me in the company hierarchy but are not top-level management.*) They proceed to ask questions about it then also relay secret political questions to me from the HR director and ask for my replies.

Comment: How do you know that the HR director is delivering these messages?

Comment: Go to your manager and discuss this.  They are probably on the list as well and should be very interested in what you have to say.  Have proof before you do.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? What is your role in company? Do you have a manager?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I know about them because they delivered the messages to me. So, basically, you're saying there's nothing that can be done, right?

Comment: @sf02 Because person A and person B keeping coming to me saying that the HR director wanted told them X, Y, and Z and she wants them to get the answer from me and take it back to her.

Comment: Is there any reasons for the downvotes that could please be explained so that I can fix the problem? Or is it just because we aren't supposed to discuss it when HR breaks the rules?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was the recipient, yes. Good point about the CEO, but I would be concerned for the original reason you mentioned.

Comment: @Hackz What are Person A and B's roles in the company? Not explicit job titles or whatever but e.g. are they workers on a similar level to you, are they managers, directors, what? Did they come to you together or separately? And would you consider they are your 'allies' in some sense, or 'enemies' or somewhat neutral? - on the scale of 'office politics alliances'? What sort of information is being distributed? - again, not explicit details but something like: "health conditions" "reason for absences" "company concerns about my job role performance" or something else?

Comment: @seventyeightist They were separate. Higher than low level managers (me) but lower than senior leadership. It was about a mix of things that HR would know but isn't supposed to disclose. It's related to "politics" at the office as to how and why she was disclosing information. HR plays both sides of the politics game and those are people she's "allies" with. I do my best to stay out of it, but I'm loyal to my boss which is the other side of that, I guess.

Comment: I don't understand why this is on hold. The OP is asking a very clear question about what he can do when he has a complaint about someone's professional behaviour at work.

Comment: OP should edit question, adding "I want X to happen"

Comment: @aaaaaa Good point. I want the behavior to stop without retribution against me.

Comment: @Hackz - What do you mean with politics? Are you in trouble for your personal beliefs, opinions or comments as a, let's say, "non-liberal"? If yes, which country?

Comment: @Battle I meant politics in more of the non-"Repub. vs. Demo." sense. They actually have that issue here too, but I just stay out of that one. Fortunately for me, this all seems to have blown over now and I'm getting over it, though I still don't like how things work like this these days...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are **almost certainly** other kinds of recourse available, though what exactly that will look like will vary depending on where you are. Check your contract or company handbook for the **grievance procedure**. Raising a formal grievance will make this something the company cannot ignore and must address. (If they don't, or fail to take it seriously, you might then have something more tangible to take to an employment lawyer).

Of course - since your grievance is with the HR director (assuming A and B are telling the truth!), and the grievance procedure will probably tell you to raise it with HR, you might be able to guess the likelihood of a positive outcome. They will still be required to respond, and you may even be able to bring in another director or C-level exec to avoid the HR director ruling on his own behaviour; but you should be realistic about what you can expect to achieve.

Whether you consider that "safe" to pursue will depend on your circumstances.

Comment: Cheers, thanks much and good advice :) I will update this with details of how it goes later, if you would like